# Swagger-UI with java - model not being generated in inheritance structure

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I got a webservice that consumes the following structure:

```
@ApiModel(discriminator = "status", subTypes = {SuccessPolicyUpdate.class, FailurePolicyUpdate.class})
public abstract class AbstractPolicyUpdate {
    private String clientId;
    private PolicyStatus status;
}
```

this is being inherited by the followign twso subclasses

```
@ApiModel(parent = AbstractPolicyUpdate.class)
public class FailurePolicyUpdate extends AbstractPolicyUpdate {
    private FailureCode code;
}

@ApiModel(parent = AbstractPolicyUpdate.class)
public class SuccessPolicyUpdate extends AbstractPolicyUpdate {
    private String policyNumber;
    private List<Inconsistency> inconsistencies = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And inconsistency is just a pojo:

```
public class Inconsistency {
    private InconsistencyCode code;
    private String oldValue;
    private String newValue;
}
```

this generates the following json:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"description":"Api Documentation","version":"1.0","title":"Api Documentation","termsOfService":"urn:tos","contact":{},"license":{"name":"Apache 2.0","url":"http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"}},"host":"localhost:8080","basePath":"/","tags":[{"name":"digital-vapz-controller","description":"Digital Vapz Controller"}],"paths":{"/api/policy":{"post":{"tags":["digital-vapz-controller"],"summary":"Update policy status","operationId":"updatePolicyStatusUsingPOST","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"Authorization","in":"header","description":"Authorization","required":true,"type":"string"},{"in":"body","name":"policyUpdate","description":"policyUpdate","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/AbstractPolicyUpdate"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"Request succesfully processed"},"201":{"description":"Created"},"400":{"description":"Invalid input parameters for this request","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/ErrorResponse"}},"401":{"description":"Invalid authorization for this request"},"403":{"description":"Forbidden"},"404":{"description":"Not Found"},"500":{"description":"Internal server error","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/ErrorResponse"}}},"deprecated":false}}},"definitions":{"AbstractPolicyUpdate":{"type":"object","discriminator":"status","properties":{"clientId":{"type":"string"},"status":{"type":"string","enum":["SUCCESS","FAILURE"]}},"title":"AbstractPolicyUpdate"},"ErrorResponse":{"type":"object","properties":{"code":{"type":"string"},"errors":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"}}},"title":"ErrorResponse"},"FailurePolicyUpdate":{"title":"FailurePolicyUpdate","allOf":[{"$ref":"#/definitions/AbstractPolicyUpdate"},{"type":"object","properties":{"clientId":{"type":"string"},"code":{"type":"string","enum":["CLIENT_ONBOARDING_KNOWN","CLIENT_RSB_CODE","CLIENT_VAPZ_EXISTS","RETRIEVING_PRODUCT","RETRIEVING_PTC","NEEDS_ANALYSIS","CREATING_POLICY","UPDATE_PTC"]},"status":{"type":"string","enum":["SUCCESS","FAILURE"]}},"title":"FailurePolicyUpdate"}]},"SuccessPolicyUpdate":{"title":"SuccessPolicyUpdate","allOf":[{"$ref":"#/definitions/AbstractPolicyUpdate"},{"type":"object","properties":{"clientId":{"type":"string"},"inconsistencies":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Inconsistency"}},"policyNumber":{"type":"string"},"status":{"type":"string","enum":["SUCCESS","FAILURE"]}},"title":"SuccessPolicyUpdate"}]}}}
```

There is a ref to Inconsistency, but the model itself is not in the generated json. What am I forgetting?
I am using io.springfox libs, version 2.9.2